Consequences of delaying entry to Japan on a 90-day visa for University visit
I'm an Indian citizen with New Zealand PR, and I've received a 90-day tourist visa for Japan to conduct an unpaid 3-month visit to a University. My visa is valid until October 1st, and I was originally planning to arrive on August 1st.
However, I'm considering postponing my trip to September 15th due to some family matters. These aren't emergencies, and I could still travel on the original dates if necessary, but I'd prefer to delay if possible.
My questions are:

What are the potential consequences of arriving in Japan 1.5 months later than my originally planned date?
Will immigration officers likely question this delay? If so, how should I approach explaining it?
Does immigration typically check the supporting documents (like university invitation letters) that were provided for the visa application?
Could this delay affect my ability to stay for the full 90 days from my new arrival date?
Is it necessary to inform the Japanese embassy about this change in plans?
Even if the university doesn't approve of the delay, my visa remains valid, so would it be alright to travel for sightseeing purposes?

Additional context:

I haven't informed the university about my potential delay yet.
I still intend to stay in Japan for the full 90 days, even with a September arrival.

I'm looking for insights from those familiar with Japanese immigration procedures or who have experienced similar situations. Any advice on how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Re Q6, I am not familiar with Japanese immigration rules, however a material change in the purpose of a trip can be a bad thing. Worst case scenario the university may be obliged to inform Japanese authorities and your visa gets cancelled.

I have entered Japan on a wide variety of visas (trainee, student, tourist, spouse) over the last 20 years, and in my experience it's getting the visa that's the hard part: as far as I can recall, I have never been asked anything at Immigration. (It's usually Customs who grills me.) That said, I'm from a low-risk country while you are not, so I would not recommend counting on this alone.
Now there's one interesting wrinkle here, which is that I'm pretty sure you've received the wrong visa: for an unpaid visit to a university you should probably be on a cultural activities or student visa, not a tourist visa. The good news is that if you do have a simple unsponsored tourist visa, you're free to change plans and immigration is extremely unlikely to care, as long as you can still support yourself, have a plausible itinerary, return flights, etc.
However, if the university did in any way sponsor your visa (meaning they wrote a letter of support, as opposed to just you claiming "I'll go to X University"), you'll definitely want to make sure they're on board with the change of plans and get that in writing.  And this would be doubly important if you had an actual work or long-term visa, which is sponsored by your host.

Thank you. That clears a lot of the doubts.
I will postpone travel to 28th September (visa expiry on 1st October, period of stay is 90 days), with a return on 26th December. The University is happy with the changes; will get that in writing. I shall also carry a printout of the same for immigration.
